# For dynamic reconfiguration, which is the main file?

Tags: ros, python, opencv, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials

In these tutorials, they have shown to create 1) a config file
2) a client file
3) a server file

I want to dynamically reconfigure the HSV values for upper range and lower range of a red color with my code.
For that I understand that I need to make a config file first (after creating the package and all those basic stuff..)

But then, other than that, do I need to have these two files -client file and server file other than my main node (that contains the code and where the variables to be configured exist originally)

OR

The main node is basically the client one?

OR

Is it the server one?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270237/for-dynamic-reconfiguration,-which-is-the-main-file?/) by [MukulKhanna](https://answers.ros.org/users/31696/mukulkhanna/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2017-09-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your existing node that does things with a color red will become the dynamic reconfigure server, which will allow other clients to connect to it and tell it to change those HSV values.

The client could be the [rqt dynamic reconfigure plugin](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_reconfigure), so you don't need to write your own client unless you want to control those values through a script or code rather than the rqt gui.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2017-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2